# setup.py and installing a python project

Tags: python

I've looked through the setup.py documentation and am still having some difficulties with what I feel should be pretty basic.

I've broken this down to a simple example project that I'm trying to get running, my project's directory layout is as follows:

```
myproject
  setup.py
  src\
    main.py
      extern\
      __init__.py
      mytest.py
```

**myproject/setup.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name = "myproject",
      package_dir = {'':"src"},
      packages = ["extern"],
      scripts = ["src/main.py"],
      )
```

**myproject/src/main.py:**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import extern.mytest as mytest

mytest.print_test()
```

**myproject/src/extern/mytest.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def print_test():
    print "YAY"
```

**myproject/src/extern/_*init*_.py is blank.**

I'm running setup.py as:

```
setup.py install --prefix ~/local
```

setup.py will complete with no errors and move main.py to ~/local/bin however when I run it I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named extern.mytest
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the module isn't under `sys.path` and that's way it cannot be found by the `import` statement.

In my case, the `extern` module was installed under `~/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/extern`. However, note that the installation path was arbitrarily set to `~/local` during the installation.

To fix that, you can set your `PYTHONPATH` variable to the location where the module is installed or add that path to `sys.path` in `main.py`.

Alternatively, instead of:

```
setup.py install --prefix ~/local
```

use:

```
setup.py install --user
```

This will install in your user site packages directory (`~/.local` in my platform) and python will be able to find the package without any problem. However, you'll probably need to change your `PATH` environment variable to include `~/.local/bin`.

Comment: Just as a follow up, @jcollado, what about installing into the python distribution's `site-packages` directory...will that be blocked by a permissions error?

Comment: Thanks, I had come across the --user option after I posted but it still seemed goofy to have site.USER_SITE default to ~/.local. Should I be going about things a different way to install things locally or is this just something I should accept?

Comment: @Droogans If you mean some directory like `/usr/local/lib/python2.x/site-packages`, yes that would require `root` permissions.

Comment: @Geoff That's strange, I've tried that and it installs the module files under `~/local/lib/python/` which isn't in my python path.

Comment: @Weboide Thanks for your spelling fixes.